# Docker container build is failing in Gitlab CI

Tags: python, docker, gitlab-ci

I have a container that has no issues building locally; however when I try to build it in a Gitlab CI pipeline, I get the following error:

`ERROR: failed to solve: failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to solve with frontend gateway.v0: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to build LLB: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt]: runc did not terminate sucessfully`

Here is what I have in my Dockerfile:

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.9.0
FROM python:3

# Prevents Python from writing pyc files.
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Keeps Python from buffering stdout and stderr to avoid situations where
# the application crashes without emitting any logs due to buffering.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

# Create a non-privileged user that the app will run under.
# See https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#user
ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser

# Copy the source code into the container.
COPY . .
# Download dependencies as a separate step to take advantage of Docker's caching.
# Leverage a cache mount to /root/.cache/pip to speed up subsequent builds.
# Leverage a bind mount to requirements.txt to avoid having to copy them into
# into this layer.
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip \
    --mount=type=bind,source=requirements.txt,target=requirements.txt \
    python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

# Switch to the non-privileged user to run the application.
USER appuser


# Expose the port that the application listens on.
#EXPOSE 8000

# Run the application.
CMD python3 main.py
```

Here's what I have in my .gilab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - deploy

publish:
  stage: deploy
  image: 
    name: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:19-dind
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache curl jq g++ make python3 py3-pip
    - pip install awscli --break-system-packages
    - aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $DOCKER_REGISTRY
    - aws --version
    - docker info
    - docker --version
  script:
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:$CI_PIPELINE_IID .
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:$CI_PIPELINE_IID
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There should be more relevant output from the job.

Comment: If locally it's working and on gitlab not... Are you sure you commited `requirements.txt`?